# Carrierwave with S3 and Cloudfront not displaying images

Tags: ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

Hello I am currently building a site using Rails and Heroku as well as GoDaddy for a custom domain name.

I am using Carrierwave with Fog, Amazon S3, and have set up a cloudfront with my Heroku domain name as the Origin Domain. Currently, the site loads up images very slow which is why I set up a cloudfront, but my carrierwave's config file doesn't seem to change the urls to the cloudfront counterparts. Here is my carrierwave config file. I would like users to be able to upload images through Carrierwave and then have those served back with my cloudfront.

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                        # required

config.fog_credentials = {
provider:              'AWS',                        # required
aws_access_key_id:     'acesskey',                        #      required
aws_secret_access_key: 'secretkey',                        # required
region:                'us-east-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
}

config.fog_directory  = 'directory'                          # required
# config.fog_public     = false    # optional, defaults to true
config.asset_host = 'randomjunk.cloudfront.net'
config.fog_public = false 
config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control' => "max-age=#{365.day.to_i}" } #     optional, defaults to {}
end
```

It works as long as config.fog_public is false but when I change it to config.fog_public = true the urls are now correct but the images are not found. Is this something to do with my configuration settings or have I set up my cloudfront with Heroku incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the settings that were used when you created the files initially. If they were created with `config.fog_public = false` they will be private files and access will be done with a special signed url to s3. I think the asset host is just used for files that are public (hence what you are seeing). If you upload files with `fog_public = true` then I don't think you would see the not found. You may also be able to just set it to true and re-save images to change that attribute (I'm less sure about specifics here, you certainly should be able to change them to public though).